# Suggestions for a web framework with no external dependencies

Tags: web-frameworks

Recently I was asked to take over the website of a small-ish non-profit organization. The website is a pretty simple setup, about a dozen pages of relatively static information, some image galleries and a main page with recent information about the organization, etc. (even the main page won't be updated very often).

My first thought was to lay down a simple CMS like Wordpress or Joomla, when I discovered something rather unfortunate. Because this is a non-profit, the website is being served off of some donated hosting without the benefit of a PHP/Ruby/Python install. What this means is that I'm limited to serving up straight HTML/CSS/JavaScript and basically nothing else.

What I'm looking for, then, is suggestions for a web development framework that, as a final step, could "pre-compile" the website into straight HTML/CSS/JavaScript that I could then upload to the server. I know I could write everything myself by hand, but there is going to be a lot of boilerplate code shared between every page that I don't want to have to copy and paste over and over again.

The only framework that comes to mind is [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), but that seems like it might be a bit overkill for my requirements. Really all I need is a decent templating framework that I could plug new content into, as basically every page will share the same header, footer and navigation.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Well... from what I've heard I believe this is what [CityDesk](http://www.fogcreek.com/CityDesk/) is designed to do, but I've never used it myself. (Obligatory disclaimer: CityDesk is sold by the same company behind StackExchange, but I have no connection to them or to either piece of software)

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of CityDesk before. Too bad, though, that it's $300 for a license (sadly the website has WAY more than 50 files, so I don't qualify for the "starter" edition).

Comment: There might be a more reasonably priced (or free) equivalent out on the web somewhere, but unfortunately I wouldn't know where to point you to find it (other than the standard Google search).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a crawler that produces the .html files from a dev server running whatever you like best. That's really what the 'pre-compile' step amounts to, after all.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea... I may have to look into it!